# How can i manage optimistic lock from database and application

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g, optimistic-locking

A Parent entity object that have some child and it's child maybe change the parent object status ,  for preventing from concurrency problem there is a nice solution that the name Is : Optimistic Lock

and [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-increment-the-parent-entity-version-whenever-a-child-entity-gets-modified-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) nice article from Vlad Mihalcea blog solve all the major problem and you dont need worry about the manage version field from parent and child action for increase the version .

but the problem is here : my object that you can imagine that as a parent object depend to about 4 child object , and the some of these child object do their actions form a procedure in database side . 
Does it logical doing the update operation for version field in database side ? or it's not how can i solve the problem ? what's the solution ?

some of my code example is here :

```
@Transactional
    public Long save(Long entityId) {
                 Parent parent= iParentService.loadByEntityId(entityId);
                 parent.setStatus(0)// known as first regstration
                 iParentService.persist(parent);
    }
```

in the child save operation in application side maybe change and update occure on parent :

```
   @Transactional
            public Long save(Long childId) {
                         Child child= iChildService.loadByEntityId(childId);
                         Parent parent = child.getParent(); 
                         parent.setStatus(1)// save complete 
                         iParentService.persist(parent);
                         iChildService.persist(child);
            }
```

and the confirm operation in database side is in the Oracle procedure and call it from application data access layer like this :

```
 Query query = session.createSQLQuery("{call    DBPK_PARENT.CONFIRM(:parentId,:userId,:userIp)} ");
    query.setParameter("parentId", parentId);
    query.setParameter("userId", userId);
    query.setParameter("userIp", userIp);
    query.executeUpdate();
```

and in the end of it run a sql command that update parent entity status lie this :

```
update Parent p 
set p.status=2 -- known as confirm status 
where p.id=parentId;
```

Comment: Come with your source code!

Comment: i put the code in my edit